# Mongodb document retrieval

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Mongodb in java. And I want to retrieve a document which is inside a document.

I am using this code for that:

```
        DB db = null;
        int count = 0;

        //Enter the day for which you want to search for logged on users
        String dayToSearch = "27-06-2012"; //Enter in the format dd-MM-yyyy

        db = DatabaseConnection.getDatabaseObject();
        Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

        for (String s : colls) {

            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(s);

            DBObject obj = coll.findOne();

            if(obj==null)
                System.out.println("This is only null.");

            DBObject obj1 = (DBObject)obj.get("LoginRequest");
            if(obj1!=null){
                String time = (String)obj1.get("Time");
                if(time==dayToSearch){
                    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                    query.put("LoginResponse", new BasicDBObject());
                    DBCursor cur1 = coll.find(query);
                    if(cur1.hasNext()){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println("It is null again!!!");
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.out.println("No.of users logged in successfully: " + count);
```

But i am getting null value at DBObject obj1 = (DBObject)obj.get("LoginRequest");. All my obj1 objects for each collection is coming out to be null. I printed obj and it's coming out to be correct. but obj1 is coming out to be null.

My database is of this form:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fead665b79eedd6a5776f38"),
        "test" : "hi",
        "NBC Connection id" : "6f829b01382d556eaf16c34617C2",
        "LoginRequest" : {
                "Time" : "27-06-2012",
                "Model" : null,
                "Version" : null,
                "Username" : "acpptu20000",
                "Password" : "*******",
                "Language" : "en",
                "Manufacturer" : null
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fead67cb79eedd6a5776f5b"),
        "GetInfoRequest" : {
                "MaxCallLogs" : 45,
                "MaxNewVoicemails" : 15,
                "GetInfoDateOptions" : 7,
                "MaxSavedVoicemails" : 15,
                "SubscribeForUpdates" : false
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to get "LoginRequest" object with date query?

Comment: see my LoginRequest is another DBObject ryt? So, I just want it to be there stored in a DBObject variable. But when I am storing that by casting it. I get it as null. But when I do obj.get("LoginRequest"). I get that printed properly.

Comment: Can u come in this chat room? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12986/discussion-between-shalki-and-parvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is much more complex than needed.
Try something like that:

```
        for(String s : colls)
        {
            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(s);
            DBCursor whatIHaveBeenLookingFor = coll.find(
                new BasicDBObject().append("LoginRequest",
                new BasicDBObject().append("Time", dayToSearch)));
        }
```

I did not test this because I don't have your database around. So it might be possible that you have to change some things. But this is how you can **easily** retrieve something from a MongoDB.

P.S.: Make sure you really have to iterate over all collections.

Comment: hey.. but this will give me the whole document

Comment: this will give me output as: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fead665b79eedd6a5776f38"),
        "test" : "hi",
        "NBC Connection id" : "6f829b01382d556eaf16c34617C2",
        "LoginRequest" : {
                "Time" : "27-06-2012",
                "Model" : null,
                "Version" : null,
                "Username" : "acpptu20000",
                "Password" : "*******",
                "Language" : "en",
                "Manufacturer" : null
        }
} And this will also be for each collection.I just want the time in string for each collection

Comment: You wrote: "I want to retrieve a document which is inside a document." Well there it is :D! But if you are not looking for all documents with an LoginRequest on dayToSearch I don't know what you are lookin for.

Comment: Hey.. what I want is to get the whole Login request document... and then in that I have time which I want...

Comment: So, please help me out for that.. plz

Comment: and I have even tried what u have suggested above... with that also I am getting it as null.

Comment: If this gives you null as well I think I can't help you.

Comment: hey i when i print obj.get("LoginRequest"). I get that document printed but it's not getting casted to DBObject. Can u please help now? What is that i am missing out? Please help.

Comment: Of which type is it than? -> obj.get("LoginRequest").getClass()